# use installed vsix template in visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I had installed `ng.Net.Template` using tool -> extention and update 
external link (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dahln.ngNetTemplate#overview)

[image]

and it is successfully installed and restart visual studio 
but not getting `ng.Net.Template` Template in a new project under `c#` -> web section.

What shall I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the link and it stated that 
 V3.1 on 10.8.2014 is Updated to Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6

Please change .Net Framework Version and select Visual C# from left menu, then it will show on your list, e.g.

[image]

If 4.6 is not is options, then install it.